# The SOAP request is giving Time Stamp Error

Tags: java, jax-ws

I am getting response through SOAP UI with "WSS TimeToLive" parameter > 0. But how to set the same in Java Code. I tried different options like
BindingProvider bindingProvider = (BindingProvider) port;
Map<String, Object> requestContext = ((BindingProvider) port).getRequestContext();
requestContext.put("com.sun.xml.ws.request.timeout", 3000);
requestContext.put("com.sun.xml.ws.connect.timeout", 4000);

and

requestContext.put("com.sun.xml.ws.security.timestamp.timeToLive", 300);

but doesn't work. I am getting the error "com.sun.xml.ws.fault.ServerSOAPFaultException: Client received SOAP Fault from server: Timestamp validation failed. Please see the server log to find more detail regarding exact cause of the failure."

Any solution ?

I have tried these option through code, but just getting the same error again...